# Yii framework: reCaptcha

Tags: php, yii, recaptcha

I implemented reCaptcha in my registration form. But i got an error when i instert the right captcha code:

CCaptchaValidator.action "captcha" is invalid. Unable to find such an action in the current controller.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new TblUsers;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['TblUsers']))
    {
                Yii::import('ext.recaptchalib',true);
                $privatekey = '6LfgNLoSAAAAAGBVyqeKK9qH_wG5HIGIDd2KotLB';
                $resp = recaptcha_check_answer($privatekey, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                        Yii::app()->request->getParam('recaptcha_challenge_field'), 
                        Yii::app()->request->getParam('recaptcha_response_field' ) );

        $model->attributes=$_POST['TblUsers'];
                if($resp->is_valid)
                {
        if($model->save())
                    if($this->_identity===null)
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($model->username,$model->password);
        $this->_identity->authenticate();
    }
    if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {
        $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
                $this->redirect(array('site/index'));

        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
    }
        }
        else
        {
    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
        }


}
```

The above code is my controler where i check the captcha. If its ok, then he should save data in the db and login, with the newly created user. If wrong code, well for now i only get a blank white page. Could need some help here please.

FAST EDIT: Ups i fixed the problem with the right code, i left some junk in the model rule, but its fine now. Even thought i still need some help to handle the thing when the code is wrong, cause i get a blank page now.

Comment: just render a different page with error or redirect to a different page without taking any user login actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just render a different page with error or redirect to a different page without taking any user login actions.

At the moment you are simply returning false if $resp is not correct. You are not rendering anything out in this case. So either render an error page

```
$this->render(......)
```

or redirect to a different page and not take any actions for login or event render the same again with error on the form field for captcha.

As a recommendation take a look at the nesting of your if statements, it is a simple action and you are making it a bit too complex.